# Using "datos" to refer to specific points

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

*Hay tres datos extremos (uno en 20mm y dos en 21mm) en la tabla*

The "datos" in the above sentence refers to are extreme data values. However, 
doesn't "datos" refer to a group of data points? If we are referring to 
specific data values, shouldn't "valores" be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **do** have three data points, one at 20mm and two at 21mm, so the collective 'datos' seems valid. Even if it is not, 'datos' is commonly used, but I agree with you that 'valores' sounds better.

Answer (score 3):

`Datos` is just the plural of `dato` (`datum` or `data point`), which means, as its English translations, a (given) piece of information. The English translation of `datos` is `data`, but `data` has more meanings than just being one of the plurals of `datum` (the other is `datums`).

So, every time you talk about given data points or values, you can use the word `dato`; and more than one of those are `datos`. The word doesn't imply grouping, but doesn't exclude it either.

I concur with Rodrigo in that `valores` sounds better but `datos` is correct.